# Unificando bases (empilhando)

Tags: r

Importei aproximadamente 400 json, agora preciso empilhar/unificar eles porem quero uma forma em que não precisa escrever o nome dos 400 arquivos na função
`x <- rbind(...)`

Alguma outra função que olha todos os arquivos no ambiente e faz isso ?

Comment: Quando importou os ficheiros que nomes tinham ou lhes deu? Há algum padrão?

Comment: ele vem como: "response_jan2021_p1", o "response_" é padrão os demais muda conforme o arquivo

Comment: Se estiver no diretório onde estão os ficheiros, tente `json_files <- list.files(pattern = "^response", full.names = TRUE)`, depois [leia os ficheiros](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=ler+json+em+r+site%3Apt.stackoverflow.com) para uma lista `json_data<- lapply(json_files, fromJSON)`. Se só tiverem um data.frame cada então está quase, basta fazer `final<-do.call(rbind, json_data)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumindo que:

1. Todos os 400 arquivos estejam todos em uma pasta;
2. O diretório de trabalho tenha sido devidamente definido como sendo esta pasta onde os arquivos estão,

Você pode usar a função `import_list()` do pacote "rio"

A função `import_list()` converte um conjunto de arquivos em uma lista.
Como seu interesse são em arquivos json, é interessante você usar a função `dir(pattern = ".json")` para selecionar apenas arquivos com este tipo de terminação.

O resultado é uma lista, onde cada elemento da lista é um dos arquivos da pasta.
Para empilhar, vc pode usar o parâmetro `rbind = T`.

Um exemplo a partir [desses arquivos .json](https://github.com/cordeiroitamar/exemplo_rio_import_list):

Uma vez baixados os arquivos e definido o diretório de trabalho no Rstudio:

```
library(rio)

import_list(dir(pattern = ".json"), setclass = "tibble", rbind = T)
```

resultado:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  nome    departamento salario `_file`            
  <chr>   <chr>          <int> <chr>              
1 Jorge   Cozinha         2000 funcionarios_1.json
2 Mariana Limpeza         4000 funcionarios_1.json
3 Carla   Gerencia       10000 funcionarios_1.json
4 Pedro   Vendas          8000 funcionarios_2.json
5 Miguel  TI              7000 funcionarios_2.json
6 Rosa    Marketing       7000 funcionarios_2.json
```

Observe que é criada uma coluna `_file` que informa a origem do arquivo do dado.

Lembrando que há um parâmetro chamado `rbind_label =`  se vc tiver necessidade de já atribuir um nome à essa coluna:

```
import_list(dir(pattern = ".json"), setclass = "tibble", rbind = T, rbind_label = "arquivo_de_origem")

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  nome    departamento salario arquivo_de_origem  
  <chr>   <chr>          <int> <chr>              
1 Jorge   Cozinha         2000 funcionarios_1.json
2 Mariana Limpeza         4000 funcionarios_1.json
3 Carla   Gerencia       10000 funcionarios_1.json
4 Pedro   Vendas          8000 funcionarios_2.json
5 Miguel  TI              7000 funcionarios_2.json
6 Rosa    Marketing       7000 funcionarios_2.json
```

Comment: Dei nota positiva, mas uma observação: o diretório de trabalho não precisa ser o mesmo dos arquivos. Pode indicar o diretório para `dir` com a opção `path`, incluindo também a opção `full.names = TRUE` para que os nomes dos arquivos incluam o caminho completo.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento @Carlos Eduardo Lagosta.